# Visual Studio problem with deploying all files of .NET Compact Framework application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, compact-framework

My application consist of an executable project and a dll library. My executable project has added the reference to the library project.

The library project contains some "content" files like .ini .bmp. The problem is that these files are not copied to the device when I deploy the executable project. Only dll file is copied. The curious thing is that all files are copied to the \ExecutableProject\bin\Debug directory on the desktop machine.

To workaround this I've set the deployment path of dll project the same as executable project and I'm deploying them both, but this solution doesn't seem to be nice.

I'm using VS2008 and my device works on Windows CE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things to check.

- Double check that the "Build Action" is set to "Content"
- Make sure that the "Copy to Output folder" is set to "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer"
- Make sure that the deployment folder for the library project is what you expect (Properties->Devices->Output File Folder)
- Make sure that the library project is set to the same target device as the executable
- Make sure the library project is set to deploy for your configuration (Build->Configuration Manager)
- Remember that if the content files are in a subfolder in the project, they will end up in a subfolder on the device

Comment: I was trying to avoid deploying both to the same folder. It takes really long time when you have several libraries (VS also tries to build the libraries twice - when building executable and when deploying). I thought that if the files are copied to the PC's output directory, they should also be deployed to the device.

Comment: @ctacke- Thanks for the detailed explination.I was struck up with same issue.Your key check list helped me to resolve.

Comment: @all -This is what i did basically to fix this issue. Go to ==>Library project ==>Properities==> Devices==>Outputfile folder (change this to %CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\YourProjectName