# Deploy custom files to mobile device during build

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile

I have an sdf file in my solution and I want it to be copied to an arbitrary place on the mobile device when I deploy. In the build events for the project, the only macro seems to point to the build output in the solution files on my computer, not to the end directory on the mobile device (Output file folder under Deployment options). When I set the property on the sdf file Copy to Output Directory - thats talking about the bin/Debug output directory on my computer where the solution files are - so, the question is, how can I deploy basically arbitrary files to arbitrary places on the mobile device?

This doesnt work as a post build event:

copy $(OutDir)*.sdf %CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\My_app

Comment: This question has been addressed at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299899/visual-studio-problem-with-deploying-all-files-of-net-compact-framework-applica

Comment: For me, it was setting the project to 'Deploy' in the config manager that made the difference

Answer (score 1):

For C++ programs, go to the project properties: *Configuration Properties*->*Deployment*->*Additional Files* and enter the files you want to deploy.

In C#, add the file to your project and open its properties. Under *Copy to Output Directory* select either *Copy if newer* or *Copy always* depending on your taste.